# Setting enum based on values from DB

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have an enum class as follows:

```
namespace Import.DataObject
{
    internal enum Status
    {
        FullTime,
        Terminated,
    }
}
```

In my main program I have a DB call then a

```
  foreach (ClientStatus status in databaseStatus)
            {
                if (status.Name == "FullTime")
                {
                }
                if (status.Name == "Terminated")
                {
                }

            }
```

How would I set the enum based on the if statements? The Name has an ID associated with it, and I want that ID to = the respecitve name in the enum, I have both the name and id available within the if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Enum.Parse`:

```
Status val = (Status)Enum.Parse(typeof(Status), status.Name);
```

If you're not sure the string is a valid enum, use `Enum.TryParse`:

```
Status? val;
if (!Enum.TryParse<Status>(status.Name, out val))
    val = null;
```

Then just cast to (int) to get the number value:

```
status.ID = (int)val;
```